# When is something that is consumed no longer impacted by the laws of kashrus?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food

Things which are not food or food which becomes unfit for a dog to eat are not subject to the laws of kashrus but what determines when something fits under those categories? For example many supplements according to koshrus orgs are considered foods and will tell you that they need hashgacha. At what point does a chemical produced in a lab become so far removed from being food that it is not impacted by the laws of kashrus?

Comment: You're asking us when something is unfit for a dog to eat? Shouldn't you be asking that on [Pets.SE]?

Comment: That's one part of the question but not limited to that

Comment: What's the other part?

Comment: You need to focus the question to a single idea. For now, I'm assuming you're asking about meds. It's a slightly complex issue, but, briefly, if the med has no flavor and is swallowed and not chewed, many authorities permit it because it's not food. And, almost everyone permits any med. even ones being blatantly non-kosher if one **must** take it to preserve ones health and no equivalent substitute may be found. E.g., my rav permitted me to take a specific brand of fish oil pill because my doctor said that the brand I was using was optimal for my health.

Comment: This is pretty subjective, see, for example, the debate over whether gelatin chemically derived from *nevillah* bones is so far from its origins as to be not only kosher but actually parve or the use of pork-derived niacin as a nutritional supplement

Comment: Re meds - I think your founding assumption is incorrect. Most meds are not considered food because they are not eaten (i.e., not chewed or eaten as other edibles are.) Therefore, any notion of kashrut wouldn't apply in the first place. My notion from reading various articles on the subject is that those who look for only kosher ingredients are enacting a stringency. Different story if there is flavor or something like chewable vitamins, cough syrups, etc.